# If the p.m.f. of $X$ is given by $f(x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$ where $0<p<1$, $x \in J^{+}$, determine the cumulative distrubution function of $X$.

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

The answer is $F(x)=1-(1-p)^{x}$
I don't understand how this might be achieved without Integration.

Is it possible for this question to be answered without Integration?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an integer valued r.v. ; you just have to compute a geometric sum, not an integral.

Comment: In case of discrete random variables it is callrd pmf and not pdf.

Comment: Can you write out a solution @geetha290krm ?

Comment: The given answer is incorrect. Hint: consider non-integer values of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that
$F(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(X=x) +  P(X=x-1) + ...P(X=1) = \sum_{i=1}^x P(X=i)$.

Therefore

\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^x P(X=i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^x p(1-p)^{i-1} \\
&= p \cdot \sum_{i=1}^x (1-p)^{i-1} \\
&= p \cdot \frac{1-(1-p)^{x}}{1-(1-p)} = 1-(1-p)^x
\end{align*}